# Working of RecordReader in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can anyone explain how the RecordReader actually works? How are the methods `nextkeyvalue()`, `getCurrentkey()` and `getprogress()` work after the program starts executing?

Answer (score 14):

(new API): The default Mapper class has a run method which looks like this:

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    setup(context);
    while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
        map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
    }
    cleanup(context);
}
```

The `Context.nextKeyValue()`, `Context.getCurrentKey()` and `Context.getCurrentValue()` methods are wrappers for the `RecordReader` methods. See the source file `src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/MapContext.java`.

So this loop executes and calls your Mapper implementation's `map(K, V, Context)` method.

Specifically, what else would you like to know?

Comment: @Chris..Thts very helpful..... and can you explain about splits & records come into picture in recordreader? I am confused...

Comment: Splits are created by the InputFormat, and are derived from the input files you pass in, whether the input files themselves are splittable, and other options you pass through like max / min split size

Comment: Each split is then processed to produce the records which are passed to the map method

Comment: @Chris.. thanks a lot..now i m clear about it.... hey i need another help.. Can u please help me out in this question . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984168/building-a-k-d-tree-using-mapreduce ..thnx..

Comment: What about getProgress()?

Comment: @ChrisWhite, what about getProgress() method, how and when it will get called and what is its significance?

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask
- runNewMapper()

Imp steps:

1. creates new mapper
2. get input split for the mapper
3. get recordreader for the split
4. initialize record reader
5. using record reader iterate through getNextKeyVal() and pass key,val to mappers map method
6. clean up