# Building Distributed KD tree using map-reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, kdtree

I am trying to build a Distributed KD tree using map-reduce. Description of Distributed KD tree can be found out here [Dkd-Tree](http://www.mohamedaly.info/research/distributed-kd-trees)

I have a feature vector of images having dimension 20. I have to build distributed kd tree 
according to above link, also Check out this image [Kdtree](https://78462f86-a-fa7ed8f8-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/mohamedaly.info/www/files/distributed-kd-trees-example.png?attachauth=ANoY7cpl8XFabo9DJ9YnOr1h0IxLO2_LtII8z7vjN6sRVoaXx_B8Yzd8zrj6e_EvE3ytAG7NY6wo-2kSZYaGSGJUxhYfEwdydOm5kOgwc9ZybpNukCkJvtkIaX20-EbJ7T7TIzbWajYXOqYh_5y6wO6QnZJvMnW9MMiDpVF_gq0_xAHWjoyJ_TPEK7uSPlnQ0z13S56-0yg-BZ_XZrXACjDUqdpjeQfDEbilrt73M_e1-SXFnRokrpY%3D&attredirects=0)
[image: kdree]

I have set of millions of images.
**So what method I can use to build the top of the tree (2nd part of the image) ?**  I am confused in the image distribution among the various nodes.

***If the tree is built HDFS in first map-reduce operation,then how can I access it in next map-reduce operation?***

Comment: if you want to access the tree in the next map reduce operation, you need to pass the root as well

Comment: have you found the solution? I am working on a similar kind of thing