# How to access a already built linked list in another program?

Tags: java, c, data-structures, linked-list

Suppose I build a linked list in one program, and then in another program I have to access it. 
How can I do that?

I tried to use a global linked list data structure in Java in one program, but I can't seem to access it in another program. I guess the reference to the linked list can not to obtained in next program.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: No, a program cannot just access memory of another program by default, nor would it know how to in this case as this variable is undefined.

Comment: Could you give a reason as to why you would *want* to do this?  Typically one keeps their data structures in the language/application that they need them for, not mixing and matching across.

Comment: try reading [ipc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) for start.

Comment: Do the programs need simultaneous access to the structure, or do you just want to get the data structure out of one program for use in another?

Comment: The search term you are looking for is *"interprocess communication"*.

Comment: @Makoto... I am building a tree in one program & trying to access  it in another ..since i need node values in next program.

Comment: @TedHopp: I want to build a tree & access whenever I want. Basically i am storing images in tree index & retrieve images whenever i want. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You essentially can't just build a linked list in one program and pass it completely to another program mainly because the heap memory of two programs is going to be different.

[image]
[Process Address Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxTnR.png)

So basically you have to use a communication mechanism of some sort to make this happen.

1 . To start with you can build the link list in one program and send only one node at a time using an RPC call to other program

2 or use a shared memory where the linked list would reside. by forcing the allocation to happen on this shared memory block with some sort of mechanism such as `placement new` .

As you are running inside a JVM. your are sharing the Java heap across your java processes , i would think that you can use RMI based mechanism to do that.

Comment: I'm tempted to down vote you for posting a picture from CS 101 that has little to do with the actual question, but your suggestions are valid.

Comment: @Jay D .....Thats a very nice explanation...... Actually i am working on hadoop. & I am trying to build a tree in HDFS. So i thought if i solve in the normal standalone java, i would be avle to do it in HDFS...I will try RMI. as you suggested...thanks... Check this out...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009714/building-distributed-kd-tree-using-map-reduce

Comment: @RickMangi The picture was just to give an idea about the process address space. its `easy` to make it complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to produce the linked list in a Java program and then pass it on to another program, you can do this by putting the list into an external form. This can be a Java serialized object (which the other program would have to interpret), or it can be XML, JSON, a home-brew format of your own design, or any number of other formats. It can then be passed to the other program via inter-process communication (a file, a socket, or other mechanism described in the link that @yair provided in his comment).

If you need some sort of two-way interaction between the Java program and the other program, then some sort of [remote procedure call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) would probably be the easiest ipc mechanism.